# Retrieving data from database gives error

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can anyone help me with this? My code won't run and I can't figure out why not.

```
    <?php
include('connect-db.php');


 if (isset($_GET['naam']))
 {
 // query db
 $naam = $_GET['naam'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM planten WHERE naam=$naam")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


 if($row)
 {
 // get data from db
 $cat = $row['cat'];
 $mintemp = $row['mintemp'];
 $uitleg = $row['uitleg'];
 $img = $row['img'];

 }
 }



?>
```

The connection is working and active, and the database name & row names are correct.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: And don't use a deprecated API

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM planten WHERE naam='".$naam."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your query statement. Since $naam is string you need to use quotes to enclose the string in query. Please chnage your query statement as below and try:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `planten` WHERE `naam` ='$naam'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your $naam is supposed to be a string. You should escape and quote it. Otherwise it'll be interpreted by SQL as a bogus column name.

```
if (isset($_GET['naam']))
{
  // query db
  $naam = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['naam']);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM planten WHERE naam='$naam'")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
  ...
```

This would be safer and easier if you [use PDO with SQL query parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). No need to escape anything or worry about quotes, because it's all taken care of for you by using a parameter.

```
if (isset($_GET['naam']))
{
  // query db
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM planten WHERE naam=?";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute([$_GET['naam']]);
  ...
```

FYI the old "mysql_connect()" API was deprecated in PHP 5.5 (June 2013), and has been removed in PHP 7.0 (Dec 2015). See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.

I recommend using PDO.